# Normalized Table Structure for Logging

Tags: sql-server, database-design, normalization, log

How can I normalize a table that has four columns for logging the latest activity for a single row:

1. Created On
2. Created By
3. Modified On
4. Modified By

We have dozens of tables, all with these 4 columns. Is there a way or pattern to normalize this in an efficient and flexible manner?

Comment: I was literally about to ask the exact same thing on here.

Comment: @RudiVisser Good we are on same boat i just pondered over this question too may be you it would help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/237225/sql-table-design-datecreated-and-dateupdated-columns

Comment: Yeah this is the thing, I almost rationalised an external table for these 2 reasons: Ease of adding another "common logging" attribute, and that it's not going to be used very often apart from auditing. On the flipside, I'm still going to need to add a FK on each table to this log table, so not sure it's worth it. Eugh.

Comment: @gbn could you try a hand on this

Comment: Just curious, why do you need a foreign key here? Are you really worried that someone is going to bypass your process and write invalid data to your audit table? And do you really want to have to delete all of the auditing data when someone deletes a row in a primary table? That seems like exactly the kind of thing you want to keep...

Comment: @AaronBertrand Just my thinking out loud to link an entity to it's corresponding value in the audit table. I'd rather that than a `Table`, `TableId` system going on in the `Audit` table.

Comment: @AaronBertrand that's exactly what i wanted to ask Rudi too. In case happens, so what you still lose nothing

Comment: What is "TableId"? Surely your auditing triggers can just insert the table name and the id doesn't need a formal link.

Comment: I'm talking simply about linking the entity in 1 table to its row on the audit table.

Comment: @RudiVisser but why do you need that? Especially since the entity could be deleted? And what audit row do you link to if an entity is modified twice (you don't really just want to track the *last* action, do you?). If you're going to audit in a separate table you may as well log every action, not just the last one.

Comment: I think I misexplained, I'm talking from the table containing simple values such as `CreationDate`, `DeletionDate`, `UpdatedDate`, `CreatedBy`, `UpdatedBy`, `DeletedBy`, etc. Not the full audit log. But thinking about it more, if these values were to be needed it may be efficient enough to calculate them dynamically based on the audit log if it had an 'action type' on it.

Comment: Right, then you really only need `Table, ID, Action, Username, EventDateTime`. But I still see no need for a formal foreign key anywhere here.

Answer (score 6):

I would suggest not logging the "latest activity" but rather keeping a full audit trail. In order to minimize space requirements, you might want three tables:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Users
(
  UserID TINYINT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, -- assuming <= 255 users
  Username NVARCHAR(128) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  /* , other columns */
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.Tables
(
  TableID TINYINT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, -- assuming <= 255 tables
  Name NVARCHAR(128) NOT NULL UNIQUE
  /* , other columns */
);
```

This auditing table assumes that all of the audited tables have an `INT` primary key (or a PK that will *fit* into `INT`). This will obviously be more complex if you have different data types, or compound primary keys, in which case you may just consider different auditing tables - still more valuable, IMHO, than only keeping the last modification for any one row.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.AuditLog
(
  TableID       TINYINT NOT NULL 
                FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.Tables(TableID),
  ID            INT, -- loose reference to entity table's PK
  Action        CHAR(1) CHECK (Action IN ('I', 'U', 'D')),
  UserID        TINYINT NULL -- just in case
                FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.Users(UserID),
  EventDateTime DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

(Note that I intentionally did not dictate what the clustered index should be, since I don't know all of your query patterns aside from the one mentioned in the question. It is quite likely that you will want to cluster leading on `EventDateTime`, especially if you are going to query for events that happened recently, and/or you are going to purge data periodically, which is never a bad idea. This will at least ensure that new rows are added to the "end" of the table instead of page splits happening all over the place if you choose something like `TableID` as the leading column.)

Now your trigger can check the user name (not sure about your authentication method, but this may be via `SUSER_SNAME()`), it knows what table it's dealing with, it can determine the action, so it just has to add the `ID`(s) from `inserted`/`deleted`. Hokey example that assumes a table named `dbo.foo` with a primary key called `FooID`:

```
INSERT dbo.tables(Name) SELECT N'dbo.foo';
GO

CREATE TRIGGER dbo.AuditFoo
ON dbo.foo
FOR INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  DECLARE @UserID TINYINT, @TableID TINYINT, @now DATETIME;

  SELECT @UserID = UserID -- could be NULL
    FROM dbo.Users WHERE Username = SUSER_SNAME();

  SELECT @TableID = TableID 
    FROM dbo.Tables WHERE Name = N'dbo.foo';

  -- inserts
  INSERT dbo.AuditLog(TableID, ID, Action, UserID)
  SELECT @TableID, FooID, 'I', @UserID
    FROM inserted AS i WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT 1 FROM deleted AS d WHERE d.FooID = i.FooID);

  -- updates
  INSERT dbo.AuditLog(TableID, ID, Action, UserID)
  SELECT @TableID, FooID, 'U', @UserID
    FROM inserted AS i WHERE EXISTS
    (SELECT 1 FROM deleted AS d WHERE d.FooID = i.FooID);

  -- deletes
  INSERT dbo.AuditLog(TableID, ID, Action, UserID)
  SELECT @TableID, FooID, 'D', @UserID
    FROM deleted AS d WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT 1 FROM inserted AS i WHERE i.FooID = d.FooID);
END
GO
```

Only one of those inserts will fire per statement / trigger invocation (well, to be pedantic, the trigger itself will fire multiple times in the event of `MERGE`).

If you don't want to keep a list of users / tables you can always populate this dynamically (though if you're not strictly controlling the list you may seriously reconsider the `TINYINT` suggestion above). E.g. to capture users you're seeing for the first time and haven't manually inventoried:

```
  SELECT @UserID = UserID FROM dbo.Users WHERE Username = SUSER_SNAME();

  IF @UserID IS NULL
  BEGIN
    INSERT dbo.Users(Username) SELECT SUSER_SNAME();
    SELECT @UserID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
  END
```

But for the table this doesn't make much sense. Just add the row when you create the trigger, and you can even hard-code the `TableID` instead of deriving it at runtime.

Once you are collecting data in `dbo.AuditLog`, you should be able to easily derive information about the *last* action of any specific type, restricted to a table, user, or even individual entity. If you need help constructing any of those queries, please start a new question with the schema, some sample rows and desired / expected results. Using [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) can be quite helpful.

Comment: Good answer (+1).  I've done much the same thing in the past with the addition of a varchar column to record some additional details about how the record was updated.  You won't necessarily want or get full before/after, but you can get more information that lets you track down who did what and why.  In one case I also included a column that indicated the source (part of the program) of the DB modification.  This can be useful for records that can be modifed from multiple high-level business processes.

Comment: But in this case you do not keep track of the values?